# Reinstall Default Windows 8 Metro Apps Without Windows Store

Tags: windows, windows-8, modern-ui, windows-store

All the default apps except Metro IE and Camera, one app installed from Windows Store crash as soon as I open them. So to fix this problem, I want to reinstall the default apps. Is there a command that does this task?

Comment: What is the message error from the crash? Additional info could maybe be found in the Event Viewer.

Comment: What resolution are you using? In the past, I've been able to run Win8, launch apps and see the splash screen, but they stop after that. In my case it was because my resolution was 1024 pixels wide, and Metro apps require 1368. At least, this was the case in the Developer Preview.

Comment: My res is 1920x1080

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Delete `%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps`.
2. Delete the following registry keys:

   ```
   HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ActivatableClasses\Package
   HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AppX*
   ```
3. Download [this](http://jumpshare.com/v/CIKQRM) and extract to `%WinDir%`. This will replace the `Windows Store` files.

If that doesn't work, run `sfc /scannow` or as a last resort, `Refresh` your PC.

Comment: The file is offline, you might want to re-upload it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no. Try reinstalling the apps from the store. If that doesn't work as well, open a terminal with administrator privileges and run

```
sfc /scannow
```

and get back with the results

Open this menu by pressing

```
Win Key + X
```

[image: Power user menu]

Comment: Then do `sfc /scannow`

Comment: sfc /scannow will give some output right? What does it say?

Comment: Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.

Comment: That's weird. Because for me it showed errors and MS Support told me to refresh. Are you using avast?

Comment: Nope. Only Windows Defender.

Comment: Try contacting MS Support.