# Windows 8 Store and Apps stuck on Loading screen

Tags: windows-8, windows-store, windows-store-app

Windows 8 Store Stuck on Loading Screen with Icon displaced:

[image]

Info: Windows 8 upgrade from Windows 7 in November. Dell XPS 15 2011 model.

I'm facing an issue with certain Windows 8 apps not loading, and as can be seen in the screenshot above the loading screen of the Windows Store itself is having issues and I can't get in.

It started about 2 weeks back, but I couldn't get around to fixing it till now because of college work. I believe it happened around the time that my internet and McAfee anti-virus started giving issues and it took me a day to resolve that.

- Running a full A/V system-scan shows no issues
- Running `sfc /scannow` gave a result saying "Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files and successfully repaired them" with a log in CBS.log, but the issue persists and I can't understand the CBS.log
- I came across a Superuser question to reinstall default apps without the store, but the link given in [the answer](https://superuser.com/a/499113) to a package of the default apps is no longer working
- I also came across [this article](http://www.extremetech.com/computing/134611-how-to-reinstall-windows-8-without-losing-your-files-and-programs) for doing a reinstall of Windows 8 without losing your desktop applications (since a normal Refresh will remove them, and I have over a year's worth of desktop apps installed that are important for work and play), but I was hoping something like a reinstall of the default apps would be easier/quicker

Examples of other apps that are stuck at loading screen or look corrupt:

- Games

  [image]
- Cut The Rope

  [image]

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This has happened to me on my windows 8 machine, I did a little searching and found that the entire windows 8 needed an update, to update windows 8 open the charm bar (on touch slide finger in from right, with mouse put it in top right corner) once the charm bar is open look at the bottom and select "Settings", in settings go to the bottom and hit the "Change PC settings" button, once this menu opens on the right panel select "Windows Update", if there is a update click the update button, but if it displays no update hit the "Check for updates now" button. If all else fails you can refresh your pc, refreshing your pc will keep all your personal items like files music and such, to refresh your pc, navigate to the PC settings (You should already be here) and in the right panel select "general" scroll down in the General settings until you find the "Refresh your PC without affecting your files" then hit the "get started" button. Hope this helped!

Comment: I happened to update my PC a couple months later, since Win 8 apps weren't top priority, and it fixed it for me. No problems also since 8.1. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem. just uninstall mcafee and download a program which completely removes everything of mcafee.

Comment: Could you please describe how is the program called and where it could be found?